# Aplicação Vuejs em container não renderiza?

Tags: vue.js, docker

Então, fiz um container de uma aplicação VueJs e ele sobe sem problema, mas ao acessar localhost:8080, aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Se eu uso "npm run dev" para testar, a aplicação sobe normal, mas no container da isso. Alguma idéia do que possa ser?

Comment: Seu servidor está de pé, mas falta um index.html pra ele abrir

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta.
Eu tenho um index.html na raiz do projeto, segue o index:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alurapic</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não conseguir fazer rodar diretamente pelo container do Vue, então criei um container de nodejs e colei dentro da pasta public do servidor o index.html e a pasta dist da aplicação Vue e funcionou, melhor que nada.